# Google Plus One button on load

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus, google-plus-one

I have used the callback attribute on Google's plus one button to perform an action when the plus one button is clicked. This works fine. My problem is that when I click the plus one button then close the page and come back, the button is still clicked (colour red) but my custom action is not performed. Is there a way to see if someone has already clicked the plus one button on a previous visit? I want to see the state of the button with out any need for user interaction on the button. My code is as follow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function customCallback(jsonParam) {
var Special = document.getElementById('special');

if(jsonParam.state == "on"){

     $('.test').show();
   }
   else{

       $('.test').hide();
        }
}
window.onload = customCallback;
</script>
```

Then I render my button

```
<g:plusone callback ="customCallback"></g:plusone>
```

If I click the button the code performs as expected and the .test div is shown. If I then return to the page the .test div is hidden again. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think the button being red when you come back is expected behaviour. Maybe you could sniff the CSS being applied to that button?

Comment: Yeah the button being red is expect. I was wondering if there is away of getting the state of the button when the page loads. The state is either on or off and is given in the callback function

Answer (score 0):

You can track the state of the button from your site. The only drawback is that external clicks of the button will not register when the user returns to your page.

Add a handler for the callback to set a cookie when the button is clicked:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-callback="cookieAdd" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
<script type=text/javascript>
function cookieAdd(args){
  if (args.state == "on"){
    document.cookie = 'enrolled=1;expires=0';
  }else{
    document.cookie = 'enrolled=0;expires=0';
  }
}
</script>
```

When the page loads, you can check whether the user has clicked the button as follows:

```
  <script>
    if (document.cookie != undefined && document.cookie.indexOf('enrolled=1') > -1){
      // button has already been clicked "on"
    }
  </script>
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with this, but be careful you aren't violating the [Google+ buttons policy](https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy).